# SQL Server Group By Hour

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm looking to get the below results grouped by the `job_number` and `hour`, so if `job_number` = 49671PH1246E (line 1-3), I'd want the hour to says hour_10 = 3 and the rest null.. and the job_number 49672PH1246F (from line 4-6), it would populate the hour_10 with 3 and the rest null. I have the code below (sorry it's long) but I can't get them to group together, any ideas?

```
SELECT 
    q.timestamp
    ,q.job_number
    ,(
        select count(q.job_number) 
        from system_log
        JOIN batch ON batch.id = system_log.batch_id
        JOIN job_line ON job_line.id = batch.job_line_id
        JOIN job ON job.id = job_line.JOB_ID 
        where system_log.descriptor = 'PRODUCED' 
            and system_log.timestamp between '2024-01-23 00:00:00' and '2024-01-23 01:00:00' 
         group by job_number
    ) AS hour_0
    ,(
        select count(job.job_number) 
        from system_log
        JOIN batch ON batch.id = system_log.batch_id
        JOIN job_line ON job_line.id = batch.job_line_id
        JOIN job ON job.id = job_line.JOB_ID 
        where system_log.descriptor = 'PRODUCED'
             and system_log.timestamp between '2024-01-23 01:00:00' and '2024-01-23 02:00:00' 
        group by job_number
    ) AS hour_1
,(select count(job.job_number) from system_log
JOIN batch ON batch.id = system_log.batch_id
JOIN job_line ON job_line.id = batch.job_line_id
JOIN job ON job.id = job_line.JOB_ID where system_log.descriptor = 'PRODUCED' and system_log.timestamp between '2024-01-23 02:00:00' and '2024-01-23 03:00:00' group by job_number) AS hour_2
,(select count(job.job_number) from system_log
JOIN batch ON batch.id = system_log.batch_id
JOIN job_line ON job_line.id = batch.job_line_id
JOIN job ON job.id = job_line.JOB_ID where system_log.descriptor = 'PRODUCED' and system_log.timestamp between '2024-01-23 03:00:00' and '2024-01-23 04:00:00' group by job_number) AS hour_3
,(select count(job.job_number) from system_log
JOIN batch ON batch.id = system_log.batch_id
JOIN job_line ON job_line.id = batch.job_line_id
JOIN job ON job.id = job_line.JOB_ID where system_log.descriptor = 'PRODUCED' and system_log.timestamp between '2024-01-23 04:00:00' and '2024-01-23 05:00:00' group by job_number) AS hour_4
,(select count(job.job_number) from system_log
JOIN batch ON batch.id = system_log.batch_id
JOIN job_line ON job_line.id = batch.job_line_id
JOIN job ON job.id = job_line.JOB_ID where system_log.descriptor = 'PRODUCED' and system_log.timestamp between '2024-01-23 05:00:00' and '2024-01-23 06:00:00' group by job_number) AS hour_5
,(select count(job.job_number) from system_log
JOIN batch ON batch.id = system_log.batch_id
JOIN job_line ON job_line.id = batch.job_line_id
JOIN job ON job.id = job_line.JOB_ID where system_log.descriptor = 'PRODUCED' and system_log.timestamp between '2024-01-23 06:00:00' and '2024-01-23 07:00:00' group by job_number) AS hour_6
,(select count(q.job_number) from system_log
JOIN batch ON batch.id = system_log.batch_id
JOIN job_line ON job_line.id = batch.job_line_id
JOIN job ON job.id = job_line.JOB_ID
JOIN formula ON formula.id = job.formula_id
JOIN commodity ON commodity.id = formula.commodity_id
JOIN stock_location on stock_location.id = system_log.stock_id
JOIN stock on stock.id = stock_location.stock_id where system_log.descriptor = 'PRODUCED' and system_log.timestamp between '2024-01-23 07:00:00' and '2024-01-23 08:00:00' and batch.formula_id = formula.id group by job_number ) AS hour_7
,(select count(job.job_number) from system_log
JOIN batch ON batch.id = system_log.batch_id
JOIN job_line ON job_line.id = batch.job_line_id
JOIN job ON job.id = job_line.JOB_ID where system_log.descriptor = 'PRODUCED' and system_log.timestamp between '2024-01-23 08:00:00' and '2024-01-23 09:00:00' group by job_number) AS hour_8
,(select count(job.job_number) from system_log
JOIN batch ON batch.id = system_log.batch_id
JOIN job_line ON job_line.id = batch.job_line_id
JOIN job ON job.id = job_line.JOB_ID where system_log.descriptor = 'PRODUCED' and system_log.timestamp between '2024-01-23 09:00:00' and '2024-01-23 10:00:00' group by job_number) AS hour_9
,(select count(job.job_number) from system_log
JOIN batch ON batch.id = system_log.batch_id
JOIN job_line ON job_line.id = batch.job_line_id
JOIN job ON job.id = job_line.JOB_ID where system_log.descriptor = 'PRODUCED' and system_log.timestamp between '2024-01-23 10:00:00' and '2024-01-23 11:00:00' group by job_number) AS hour_10
,(select count(job.job_number) from system_log
JOIN batch ON batch.id = system_log.batch_id
JOIN job_line ON job_line.id = batch.job_line_id
JOIN job ON job.id = job_line.JOB_ID where system_log.descriptor = 'PRODUCED' and system_log.timestamp between '2024-01-23 11:00:00' and '2024-01-23 12:00:00' group by job_number) AS hour_11
,(select count(job.job_number) from system_log
JOIN batch ON batch.id = system_log.batch_id
JOIN job_line ON job_line.id = batch.job_line_id
JOIN job ON job.id = job_line.JOB_ID where system_log.descriptor = 'PRODUCED' and system_log.timestamp between '2024-01-23 12:00:00' and '2024-01-23 13:00:00' group by job_number) AS hour_12
,(select count(job.job_number) from system_log
JOIN batch ON batch.id = system_log.batch_id
JOIN job_line ON job_line.id = batch.job_line_id
JOIN job ON job.id = job_line.JOB_ID where system_log.descriptor = 'PRODUCED' and system_log.timestamp between '2024-01-23 13:00:00' and '2024-01-23 14:00:00' group by job_number) AS hour_13
,(select count(job.job_number) from system_log
JOIN batch ON batch.id = system_log.batch_id
JOIN job_line ON job_line.id = batch.job_line_id
JOIN job ON job.id = job_line.JOB_ID where system_log.descriptor = 'PRODUCED' and system_log.timestamp between '2024-01-23 14:00:00' and '2024-01-23 15:00:00' group by job_number) AS hour_14
,(select count(job.job_number) from system_log
JOIN batch ON batch.id = system_log.batch_id
JOIN job_line ON job_line.id = batch.job_line_id
JOIN job ON job.id = job_line.JOB_ID where system_log.descriptor = 'PRODUCED' and system_log.timestamp between '2024-01-23 15:00:00' and '2024-01-23 16:00:00' group by job_number) AS hour_15
,(select count(job.job_number) from system_log
JOIN batch ON batch.id = system_log.batch_id
JOIN job_line ON job_line.id = batch.job_line_id
JOIN job ON job.id = job_line.JOB_ID where system_log.descriptor = 'PRODUCED' and system_log.timestamp between '2024-01-23 16:00:00' and '2024-01-23 17:00:00' group by job_number) AS hour_16
,(select count(job.job_number) from system_log
JOIN batch ON batch.id = system_log.batch_id
JOIN job_line ON job_line.id = batch.job_line_id
JOIN job ON job.id = job_line.JOB_ID where system_log.descriptor = 'PRODUCED' and system_log.timestamp between '2024-01-23 17:00:00' and '2024-01-23 18:00:00' group by job_number) AS hour_17
,(select count(job.job_number) from system_log
JOIN batch ON batch.id = system_log.batch_id
JOIN job_line ON job_line.id = batch.job_line_id
JOIN job ON job.id = job_line.JOB_ID where system_log.descriptor = 'PRODUCED' and system_log.timestamp between '2024-01-23 18:00:00' and '2024-01-23 19:00:00' group by job_number) AS hour_18
,(select count(job.job_number) from system_log
JOIN batch ON batch.id = system_log.batch_id
JOIN job_line ON job_line.id = batch.job_line_id
JOIN job ON job.id = job_line.JOB_ID where system_log.descriptor = 'PRODUCED' and system_log.timestamp between '2024-01-23 19:00:00' and '2024-01-23 20:00:00' group by job_number) AS hour_19
,(select count(job.job_number) from system_log
JOIN batch ON batch.id = system_log.batch_id
JOIN job_line ON job_line.id = batch.job_line_id
JOIN job ON job.id = job_line.JOB_ID where system_log.descriptor = 'PRODUCED' and system_log.timestamp between '2024-01-23 20:00:00' and '2024-01-23 21:00:00' group by job_number) AS hour_20
,(select count(job.job_number) from system_log
JOIN batch ON batch.id = system_log.batch_id
JOIN job_line ON job_line.id = batch.job_line_id
JOIN job ON job.id = job_line.JOB_ID where system_log.descriptor = 'PRODUCED' and system_log.timestamp between '2024-01-23 21:00:00' and '2024-01-23 22:00:00' group by job_number) AS hour_21
,(select count(job.job_number) from system_log
JOIN batch ON batch.id = system_log.batch_id
JOIN job_line ON job_line.id = batch.job_line_id
JOIN job ON job.id = job_line.JOB_ID where system_log.descriptor = 'PRODUCED' and system_log.timestamp between '2024-01-23 22:00:00' and '2024-01-23 23:00:00' group by job_number) AS hour_22
,(select count(job.job_number) from system_log
JOIN batch ON batch.id = system_log.batch_id
JOIN job_line ON job_line.id = batch.job_line_id
JOIN job ON job.id = job_line.JOB_ID where system_log.descriptor = 'PRODUCED' and system_log.timestamp between '2024-01-23 23:00:00' and '2024-01-23 23:59:59' group by job_number) AS hour_23
,q.code
,q.description
FROM
(
SELECT
system_log.timestamp
,job.job_number
,commodity.code
,commodity.description
FROM
system_log
JOIN batch ON batch.id = system_log.batch_id
JOIN job_line ON job_line.id = batch.job_line_id
JOIN job ON job.id = job_line.JOB_ID
JOIN formula ON formula.id = job.formula_id
JOIN commodity ON commodity.id = formula.commodity_id
JOIN stock_location on stock_location.id = system_log.stock_id
JOIN stock on stock.id = stock_location.stock_id
WHERE
system_log.descriptor = 'PRODUCED' and system_log.timestamp between '2024-01-23' and '2024-01-24'
GROUP BY job_number, timestamp, commodity.code, commodity.description, descriptor, job_line.batches_completed
) q
GROUP BY 
 q.timestamp
,q.job_number
,q.code
,q.description
ORDER BY 
q.job_number
```

[image: Table Of Results Image]

I tried the code, and want them to be grouped by job_number and hour_x, that way I can generate a report on how many batches per hour, per job and per total were done in a day. This is set to be reported in a single 24 hour day only`

Comment: 1) Please provide a [mre] with emphasis on minimal, we don't want your production code, we want you to cut it down to the bare bones that illustrates the issue. 2) Ensure you provide sample data and desired results, 3) Do not use images, use formatted (markdown) text.

Comment: **NO ONE** is going to wade through a big wall of text like that. Take a few minutes to format the code to use readable indentation and you're much more likely to get an answer. I've even done the first few lines for you to get you started. You might even find it makes the issue obvious and you can solve it yourself. The results are also not readable. Stack Overflow has table formatting built in... use that.

Comment: You should check out how conditional aggregation works. Unless you're getting paid by the line that is

Answer (score 2):

Let's see if we can't simplify this just a bit:

```
SELECT j.job_number
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN datepart(hour, sl.timestamp) = 0 THEN 1 END) Hour_0
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN datepart(hour, sl.timestamp) = 1 THEN 1 END) Hour_1
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN datepart(hour, sl.timestamp) = 2) THEN 1 END) Hour_2
-- ...

FROM system_log sl
JOIN batch b ON b.id = sl.batch_id
JOIN job_line jl ON jl.id = b.job_line_id
JOIN job ON j.id = jl.JOB_ID
WHERE sl.descriptor = 'PRODUCED' 
   AND sl.timestamp >= '20240123' AND sl.timestamp < '20240124'
GROUP BY j.job_number
```

Comment: Thank you, that helped, had to change it a little bit but I got what I needed

Answer (score -1):

Resolved, I used the following:

```
SELECT 
q.job_number
,q.code
,q.description
,COUNT(CASE WHEN datepart(hour, q.timestamp) = 0 THEN 1 END) Hour_0
,SUM(COUNT(CASE WHEN datepart(hour, q.timestamp) = 0 THEN 1 END)) OVER() as Hour_0_Total
,COUNT(CASE WHEN datepart(hour, q.timestamp) = 1 THEN 2 END) Hour_1
,SUM(COUNT(CASE WHEN datepart(hour, q.timestamp) = 1 THEN 2 END)) OVER() as Hour_1_Total
,COUNT(CASE WHEN datepart(hour, q.timestamp) = 2 THEN 3 END) Hour_2
,SUM(COUNT(CASE WHEN datepart(hour, q.timestamp) = 2 THEN 3 END)) OVER() as Hour_2_Total
,COUNT(CASE WHEN datepart(hour, q.timestamp) = 3 THEN 4 END) Hour_3
,SUM(COUNT(CASE WHEN datepart(hour, q.timestamp) = 3 THEN 4 END)) OVER() as Hour_3_Total
,COUNT(CASE WHEN datepart(hour, q.timestamp) = 4 THEN 5 END) Hour_4
,SUM(COUNT(CASE WHEN datepart(hour, q.timestamp) = 4 THEN 5 END)) OVER() as Hour_4_Total
,COUNT(CASE WHEN datepart(hour, q.timestamp) = 5 THEN 6 END) Hour_5
,SUM(COUNT(CASE WHEN datepart(hour, q.timestamp) = 5 THEN 6 END)) OVER() as Hour_5_Total
,COUNT(CASE WHEN datepart(hour, q.timestamp) = 6 THEN 7 END) Hour_6
,SUM(COUNT(CASE WHEN datepart(hour, q.timestamp) = 6 THEN 7 END)) OVER() as Hour_6_Total
,COUNT(CASE WHEN datepart(hour, q.timestamp) = 7 THEN 8 END) Hour_7
,SUM(COUNT(CASE WHEN datepart(hour, q.timestamp) = 7 THEN 8 END)) OVER() as Hour_7_Total
,COUNT(CASE WHEN datepart(hour, q.timestamp) = 8 THEN 9 END) Hour_8
,SUM(COUNT(CASE WHEN datepart(hour, q.timestamp) = 8 THEN 9 END)) OVER() as Hour_8_Total
,COUNT(CASE WHEN datepart(hour, q.timestamp) = 9 THEN 10 END) Hour_9
,SUM(COUNT(CASE WHEN datepart(hour, q.timestamp) = 9 THEN 10 END)) OVER() as Hour_9_Total
,COUNT(CASE WHEN datepart(hour, q.timestamp) = 10 THEN 11 END) Hour_10
,SUM(COUNT(CASE WHEN datepart(hour, q.timestamp) = 10 THEN 11 END)) OVER() as Hour_10_Total
,COUNT(CASE WHEN datepart(hour, q.timestamp) = 11 THEN 12 END) Hour_11
,SUM(COUNT(CASE WHEN datepart(hour, q.timestamp) = 11 THEN 12 END)) OVER() as Hour_11_Total
,COUNT(CASE WHEN datepart(hour, q.timestamp) = 12 THEN 13 END) Hour_12
,SUM(COUNT(CASE WHEN datepart(hour, q.timestamp) = 12 THEN 13 END)) OVER() as Hour_12_Total
,COUNT(CASE WHEN datepart(hour, q.timestamp) = 13 THEN 14 END) Hour_13
,SUM(COUNT(CASE WHEN datepart(hour, q.timestamp) = 13 THEN 14 END)) OVER() as Hour_13_Total
,COUNT(CASE WHEN datepart(hour, q.timestamp) = 14 THEN 15 END) Hour_14
,SUM(COUNT(CASE WHEN datepart(hour, q.timestamp) = 14 THEN 15 END)) OVER() as Hour_14_Total
,COUNT(CASE WHEN datepart(hour, q.timestamp) = 15 THEN 16 END) Hour_15
,SUM(COUNT(CASE WHEN datepart(hour, q.timestamp) = 15 THEN 16 END)) OVER() as Hour_15_Total
,COUNT(CASE WHEN datepart(hour, q.timestamp) = 16 THEN 17 END) Hour_16
,SUM(COUNT(CASE WHEN datepart(hour, q.timestamp) = 16 THEN 17 END)) OVER() as Hour_16_Total
,COUNT(CASE WHEN datepart(hour, q.timestamp) = 17 THEN 18 END) Hour_17
,SUM(COUNT(CASE WHEN datepart(hour, q.timestamp) = 17 THEN 18 END)) OVER() as Hour_17_Total
,COUNT(CASE WHEN datepart(hour, q.timestamp) = 18 THEN 19 END) Hour_18
,SUM(COUNT(CASE WHEN datepart(hour, q.timestamp) = 18 THEN 19 END)) OVER() as Hour_18_Total
,COUNT(CASE WHEN datepart(hour, q.timestamp) = 19 THEN 20 END) Hour_19
,SUM(COUNT(CASE WHEN datepart(hour, q.timestamp) = 19 THEN 20 END)) OVER() as Hour_19_Total
,COUNT(CASE WHEN datepart(hour, q.timestamp) = 20 THEN 21 END) Hour_20
,SUM(COUNT(CASE WHEN datepart(hour, q.timestamp) = 20 THEN 21 END)) OVER() as Hour_20_Total
,COUNT(CASE WHEN datepart(hour, q.timestamp) = 21 THEN 22 END) Hour_21
,SUM(COUNT(CASE WHEN datepart(hour, q.timestamp) = 21 THEN 22 END)) OVER() as Hour_21_Total
,COUNT(CASE WHEN datepart(hour, q.timestamp) = 22 THEN 23 END) Hour_22
,SUM(COUNT(CASE WHEN datepart(hour, q.timestamp) = 22 THEN 23 END)) OVER() as Hour_22_Total
,COUNT(CASE WHEN datepart(hour, q.timestamp) = 23 THEN 0 END) Hour_23
,SUM(COUNT(CASE WHEN datepart(hour, q.timestamp) = 23 THEN 0 END)) OVER() as Hour_23_Total
,COUNT(q.job_number) as batches_produced
FROM
(
SELECT
system_log.timestamp
,job.job_number
,commodity.code
,commodity.description
FROM
system_log
JOIN batch ON batch.id = system_log.batch_id
JOIN job_line ON job_line.id = batch.job_line_id
JOIN job ON job.id = job_line.JOB_ID
JOIN formula ON formula.id = job.formula_id
JOIN commodity ON commodity.id = formula.commodity_id
WHERE
system_log.descriptor = 'PRODUCED' and system_log.timestamp BETWEEN '2023-04-10' and '2023-04-11'
GROUP BY job_number,system_log.timestamp, commodity.code, commodity.description, batch.completion_date
) q
GROUP BY q.job_number, q.code,q.description
ORDER BY 
q.job_number
```

Comment: you'll thank yourself if you learn to format your queries in a reasonable way that makes better use of indentation.

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**